# Traceroute log to CSV Perl parser Regex issue

Tags: perl

I have written some shell scripts that run trace routes to hosts and then saves them to a file. This works perfectly and outputs all data to a `.log` file as intended.

I have then gone ahead and written a simple Perl script that turns this `.log` into a `.csv` file so I can import it to excel. However, upon looking at the `.csv` file produced the Perl script I wrote has problem when dealing with packets which have IP addresses with the times.

For example this line from the `.log` file is parsed perfectly:

`1  139.222.0.1  0.941 ms  1.446 ms  1.996 ms`

into the `.csv` file as:

`1,139.222.0.1,0.941 ms,1.446 ms,1.996 ms`

However, should the traceroute return anything similar to this which is stored in the `.log` file:

`12  154.54.57.98  7.579 ms 154.54.74.42  7.009 ms 130.117.0.58  7.480 ms`

Then it is parsed into the `.csv` file incorrectly and ruins the entire following `.csv` file (this is a made up example):

`11,213.248.77.134,7.432 ms,9.038 ms,213.248.70.238 ms`

As you can see the IP given with the hop time is now used as the time it took for the packet.

I am very confused on how to fix this! Any help would be appreciated, here is a code snippet that turns the log to csv for each hop :

```
  my $start = "'Hop','IP','T1','T2','T3'";
  print OUTPUT "\n$_$start\n";
 };

  print OUTPUT "$1,$2,$3 ms,$4 ms,$5 ms\n" if (/(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+ms\s+(\S+)\s+ms\s+(\S+)/);
```

**EDIT**

Wrote my own fix that adds extra csv columns and inserts into them appropriately

```
  my $start = "'Hop','IP','T1','T1IP','T2','T2IP',T3'";
  print OUTPUT "\n$_$start\n";
 };

 if (/(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+ms\s+(\S+)\s+ms\s+(\S+)\s+ms/){
 print OUTPUT "$1,$2,$3 ms, ,$4 ms, ,$5 ms\n";

}elsif (/(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+ms\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+ms\s+(\S+)\s+ms/){
 print OUTPUT "$1,$2,$3 ms,$4,$5 ms, ,$6 ms\n";

}elsif (/(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+ms\s+(\S+)\s+ms\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+ms/){
 print OUTPUT "$1,$2,$3 ms, ,$4 ms,$5,$6 ms\n";

}elsif (/(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+ms\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+ms\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+ms/){
 print OUTPUT "$1,$2,$3 ms,$4,$5 ms,$6,$7 ms\n";
};
```

Thanks for all your help/responses!

Comment: Please show the code that isn't working

Comment: the code that isnt working is  

 print OUTPUT "$1,$2,$3 ms,$4 ms,$5 ms\n" if (/(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+ms\s+(\S+)\s+ms\s+(\S+)/);
 
 as this only account for if the traceroute only returns time values and not time and IP values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the data you show, I would just split the line on whitespace not followed by `ms`.

```
my $csv = join ',', split /\s+(?!ms)/, $line;
```

But the code you show implies that the trace route information is mingled with dates, so this may not be appropriate.

**Update**

Having seen your data, I think this should do what you want.

Note that the header names that you print don't correspond to the data where you have more than one IP address on the line. I'm not sure what you want to do in that case.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $logfile    = 'trace.log';
my $parsedfile = 'trace.csv';

open my $infh,  '<', $logfile;
open my $outfh, '>', $parsedfile;

while (<$infh>) {
    if (/^[a-z]{3}\s+[a-z]{3}/i) {
        print $outfh $_;
        print $outfh qq{"Hop","IP","T1","T2","T3"\n};
    }
    elsif (/^\s*\d/) {
        chomp;
        s/^\s+//;
        print $outfh join(',', split /\s+(?!ms)/), "\n";
    }
}
```

**output**

```
Wed Mar  6 01:58:49 GMT 2013
"Hop","IP","T1","T2","T3"
1,139.222.0.1,0.987 ms,1.412 ms,1.971 ms
2,10.0.0.1,0.445 ms,0.500 ms,0.552 ms
3,172.16.0.34,1.667 ms,0.875 ms,1.503 ms
4,193.62.92.71,1.939 ms,2.547 ms,2.529 ms
5,146.97.130.249,2.561 ms,2.447 ms,4.615 ms
6,146.97.65.85,5.309 ms,6.709 ms,5.376 ms
7,146.97.65.65,7.133 ms,7.340 ms,7.323 ms
8,146.97.65.37,9.362 ms,9.750 ms,9.804 ms
9,146.97.35.125,9.473 ms,9.485 ms,8.815 ms
10,213.248.84.177,8.798 ms,9.171 ms,8.505 ms
11,213.248.77.134,8.333 ms,7.837 ms,213.248.70.238,7.721 ms
12,154.54.74.42,7.879 ms,154.54.72.186,7.450 ms,154.54.57.94,7.862 ms
13,66.28.4.189,81.812 ms,81.433 ms,154.54.30.129,80.648 ms
14,154.54.30.17,217.548 ms,154.54.43.10,217.531 ms,66.28.4.222,109.029 ms
15,154.54.27.53,216.490 ms,154.54.42.241,195.393 ms,154.54.27.53,216.389 ms
16,154.54.42.241,195.141 ms,193.123 ms,192.900 ms
17,154.54.28.85,99.232 ms,154.54.5.229,99.127 ms,98.931 ms
18,154.54.31.21,102.739 ms,154.54.5.229,99.086 ms,98.803 ms
19,154.54.31.21,102.719 ms,38.122.60.46,101.206 ms,101.052 ms
20,216.234.104.254,102.619 ms,38.122.60.46,101.415 ms,101.275 ms
21,75.98.163.130,100.512 ms,100.409 ms,100.485 ms
```

Comment: the date thing is simply as a header and is only printed once at the start of the log/csv file as this trace route runs repeatedly and I need it for reference, there is no other dates printed once traceroute is started :) thanks for your reply ill have a look into that method thank you

Comment: Having understood you question better I think my solution may not be appropriate. A sample of the full input would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I've updated my answer to provide what I think is a working program

Comment: This is exactly what I have been trying, I managed to create a similar program using a series of elsif statements, however this only half worked and your code is much neater and easier to understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also added my own answer to my original question to deal with the header issues :) thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A guess on what you want, without the header codes:

```
my $re_ip = qr/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+/;
while(<INPUT>) {
  my @v = split(/($re_ip)/);
  my $hop = (shift(@v) =~ /(\d+)/)[0]; # the hop number?
  for my $v (@v) {
    if ($v =~ /$re_ip/) {
      print OUTPUT "$hop,$v,";
    } else {
      my @ms = $v =~ /(\S+\s+ms)/g;
      print OUTPUT join(",", @ms), "\n";
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll have a look at this also :)